# For customer token creation by REST Api,Token is been return unknow format or extra length. In magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, token

For customer token creationby **REST** Api,Token is been return unknow format or extra length. In magento 2,Can anyone have any idea why it is return unknow length or so.Please find the below screen shot.For more details.

https://prnt.sc/izkji4

thanks in adavance.

Comment: i am getting this error in vendor file of Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService @ManthanDave

Comment: Yup @ManthanDave

Comment: no it's giving me the exact token please find the below screen shot. https://prnt.sc/izlefl

Comment: okay got it - show the screenshot of Authorization tab of postman and Headers tab of postman - I am getting token without this additional data string

Comment: Header Tab  https://prnt.sc/izm4mj  Authorization Tab https://prnt.sc/izm4t3

Comment: okay got it - so which is your magento2 root directory ? its pranay right ? - if yes then url should be - http://192.168.1.55/pranay/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Comment: 192.168.1.55/pranay/rest/V1/integration/customer/token with this url u need to pass parameters like username and password to generate token i tried but not getting the exact toke n